# AngularJS $http call not outputting Array

Tags: angularjs

Trying to grab an associative array through an AngularJS $http call, but instead of getting the actual array, I am getting the string "Array".

Here is my $http call:

```
$http({
            method : 'POST', 
            url : '[myPHPfile].php', 
            data : 'data=' + $scope.placementID,
            headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

And this is [myPHPfile].php (omitted other lines):

```
echo someFunctionInAnotherFile($_POST['data']);
```

I know I am grabbing the array because doing echo var_dump(theArray) in [myPHPfile].php and alert(data) in the success part of the $http call, I get:

```
array(8) { 
   ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
   ["id_key"]=>
   string(1) "2"
   ...
}
```

But without the var_dump, and I do an alert(data["id"]) under success, nothing happens. And doing an alert(data[1]) I get "r", so not sure why the returned data becomes a string called "Array".

I have tried echo json_encode(...) in[myPHPfile].php and alert(JSON.parse(data)) under success, but that didn't work either.

Just trying to access a simple array, but need help. :(

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here.

json_encode() from PHP should work, but make sure the header is set correctly.

```
<?php 
   header('Content-type: application/json'); 
   echo json_encode(someFunctionInAnotherFile($_POST['data']));
?>
```

The second issue is that json_encode will turn a PHP "array" into an object if the array is an "associative" array and a regular array otherwise.

Lastly, displaying raw post data is incredibly dangerous and you should not do it.

Comment: I added the header, and tried doing an alert(JSON.parse(data)) as well as:
var test = JSON.parse(data); alert(test["id"]);

on the javascript end, but it isn't returning anything. It is an [object Object] getting passed though.

Comment: @JeffZhan  You should try to debug only 1 thing at a time, make sure your php file when visited in a browser is echoing out a structure you understand.  After that's good on the javascript side use console.log(data) to be able to inspect the data using the Chrome console.  If you end up with an associative array/JSON Object not JSON Array you can use 'echo json_encode(array_values($returnedData));' to convert it

Comment: As @shaunhusain mentioned, you'll want to use console.log and I don't think you'll need to the JSON.parse, if I remember correctly $http will do that for you if the mime type is set properly.